# magento upgradation -1.4 to 1.8

Tags: magento

I tried upgrading where I successfully upgraded to 1.4.2 from 1.4.1 
but the frontend stopped working. Also, phpmyadmin completely stopped.

Below is my error log in  `/opt/lamp/logs`.

Does anyone know where exactly to look for what's causing the error in this big log?

```
[Fri Jan 24 17:16:44.072704 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 1180] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 24 17:16:44.072796 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 1180] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 24 17:16:44.072825 2014] [suexec:notice] [pid 1180] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /opt/lampp/bin/suexec)
[Fri Jan 24 17:16:44.218834 2014] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1335] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jan 24 17:16:45.030837 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 1335] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 24 17:16:45.030929 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 1335] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 24 17:16:45.030997 2014] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1335] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Jan 24 17:16:45.039496 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1335] AH00163: Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 24 17:16:45.039531 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1335] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -D SSL -D PHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log'
[Fri Jan 24 17:17:41.073939 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 1890] [client 127.0.0.1:56956] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/
[Fri Jan 24 17:17:50.020021 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 1891] [client 127.0.0.1:56983] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/
[Fri Jan 24 17:17:51.154603 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 1891] [client 127.0.0.1:56983] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/
[Fri Jan 24 17:17:51.602371 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 1891] [client 127.0.0.1:56983] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/
[Fri Jan 24 17:17:51.901841 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 1891] [client 127.0.0.1:56983] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/
[Fri Jan 24 17:20:01.327548 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 1892] [client 127.0.0.1:56987] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/
[Fri Jan 24 17:20:02.489854 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 1892] [client 127.0.0.1:56987] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/
[Fri Jan 24 17:20:42.243495 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1335] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jan 24 17:20:51.085988 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2967] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 24 17:20:51.086085 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2967] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 24 17:20:51.086113 2014] [suexec:notice] [pid 2967] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /opt/lampp/bin/suexec)
[Fri Jan 24 17:20:51.216881 2014] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 2968] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jan 24 17:20:52.074917 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2968] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 24 17:20:52.074967 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2968] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 24 17:20:52.075005 2014] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 2968] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Jan 24 17:20:52.081177 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2968] AH00163: Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 24 17:20:52.081213 2014] [core:notice] [pid 2968] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -D SSL -D PHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log'
[Fri Jan 24 17:40:47.075100 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 1188] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 24 17:40:47.086940 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 1188] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 24 17:40:47.086998 2014] [suexec:notice] [pid 1188] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /opt/lampp/bin/suexec)
[Fri Jan 24 17:40:47.242800 2014] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1502] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jan 24 17:40:48.050110 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 1502] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 24 17:40:48.050170 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 1502] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 24 17:40:48.050214 2014] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1502] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Jan 24 17:40:48.055872 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1502] AH00163: Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 24 17:40:48.055913 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1502] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -D SSL -D PHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log'
[Fri Jan 24 17:50:03.664870 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 2506] [client 127.0.0.1:44824] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Jan 24 17:58:43.173383 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 2512] [client 127.0.0.1:44945] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Jan 24 18:02:47.290956 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1502] AH00051: child pid 2915 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /opt/lampp
[Fri Jan 24 18:05:48.701079 2014] [:error] [pid 2506] [client 127.0.0.1:45082] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:05:59.281046 2014] [:error] [pid 2932] [client 127.0.0.1:45083] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:06:18.870329 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 2001] [client 127.0.0.1:45088] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Jan 24 18:09:28.481096 2014] [:error] [pid 2001] [client 127.0.0.1:45098] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:10:05.300624 2014] [:error] [pid 2946] [client 127.0.0.1:45114] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:10:05.691793 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1502] AH00051: child pid 3781 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /opt/lampp
[Fri Jan 24 18:10:12.901312 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 1998] [client 127.0.0.1:45116] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Jan 24 18:10:19.200353 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:45122] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Jan 24 18:21:01.813878 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:45350] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:21:03.603027 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:45350] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:21:04.886698 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:45350] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:21:05.105651 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:45350] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:21:05.278352 2014] [:error] [pid 1998] [client 127.0.0.1:45351] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:22:00.454583 2014] [:error] [pid 2946] [client 127.0.0.1:45403] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:22:57.866575 2014] [:error] [pid 3752] [client 127.0.0.1:45434] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:22:58.061249 2014] [:error] [pid 3752] [client 127.0.0.1:45434] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:23:24.403970 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 2001] [client 127.0.0.1:45443] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Jan 24 18:23:47.017177 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 3754] [client 127.0.0.1:45452] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Jan 24 18:23:53.612522 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 2946] [client 127.0.0.1:45463] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Jan 24 18:23:56.602871 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 2001] [client 127.0.0.1:45466] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Jan 24 18:24:02.936633 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:45472] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Jan 24 18:27:07.836253 2014] [:error] [pid 3753] [client 127.0.0.1:45605] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:27:09.725328 2014] [:error] [pid 3753] [client 127.0.0.1:45605] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:27:11.510547 2014] [:error] [pid 3753] [client 127.0.0.1:45605] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:27:13.086073 2014] [:error] [pid 3753] [client 127.0.0.1:45605] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:27:13.252462 2014] [:error] [pid 2506] [client 127.0.0.1:45606] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:27:13.403045 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:45607] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:27:13.503701 2014] [:error] [pid 2946] [client 127.0.0.1:45608] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:29:54.146949 2014] [:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:45873] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:30:39.799300 2014] [:error] [pid 3753] [client 127.0.0.1:45991] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529
[Fri Jan 24 18:30:39.897294 2014] [:error] [pid 3753] [client 127.0.0.1:45991] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228\nStack trace:\n#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)\n#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)\n#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)\n#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `core_se...', Array)\n#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `core_se...', Array)\n#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(604): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `core_se...', Array)\n#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Session.php(199): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('core_session in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 234
[Fri Jan 24 18:40:57.681009 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:46634] PHP Warning:  include(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:40:57.681057 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:46634] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/local:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/community:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:40:57.681071 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:46634] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:02.823272 2014] [:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:46643] PHP Warning:  include(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:02.823324 2014] [:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:46643] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/local:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/community:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:02.823339 2014] [:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:46643] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:06.232257 2014] [:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:46643] PHP Warning:  include(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:06.232316 2014] [:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:46643] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/local:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/community:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:06.232331 2014] [:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:46643] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:08.058339 2014] [:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:46643] PHP Warning:  include(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:08.058388 2014] [:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:46643] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/local:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/community:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:08.058411 2014] [:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:46643] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:10.021820 2014] [:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:46643] PHP Warning:  include(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:10.021866 2014] [:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:46643] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/local:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/community:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:10.021880 2014] [:error] [pid 2510] [client 127.0.0.1:46643] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:18.703821 2014] [:error] [pid 2506] [client 127.0.0.1:46684] PHP Warning:  include(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:18.703868 2014] [:error] [pid 2506] [client 127.0.0.1:46684] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/local:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/community:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:18.703882 2014] [:error] [pid 2506] [client 127.0.0.1:46684] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:41.511820 2014] [:error] [pid 4590] [client 127.0.0.1:46704] PHP Warning:  include(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:41.511972 2014] [:error] [pid 4590] [client 127.0.0.1:46704] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/local:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/community:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:41.511997 2014] [:error] [pid 4590] [client 127.0.0.1:46704] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:43.294737 2014] [:error] [pid 4590] [client 127.0.0.1:46704] PHP Warning:  include(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:43.294842 2014] [:error] [pid 4590] [client 127.0.0.1:46704] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/local:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/community:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:43.294862 2014] [:error] [pid 4590] [client 127.0.0.1:46704] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:44.154850 2014] [:error] [pid 4590] [client 127.0.0.1:46704] PHP Warning:  include(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:44.154905 2014] [:error] [pid 4590] [client 127.0.0.1:46704] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/local:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/community:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:41:44.154928 2014] [:error] [pid 4590] [client 127.0.0.1:46704] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247
[Fri Jan 24 18:43:34.357140 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:46818] PHP Warning:  include(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:43:34.357197 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:46818] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/local:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/community:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:43:34.357211 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:46818] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247
[Fri Jan 24 18:43:35.823166 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:46818] PHP Warning:  include(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:43:35.823211 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:46818] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/local:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/community:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:43:35.823225 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:46818] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247
[Fri Jan 24 18:43:40.071212 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:46818] PHP Warning:  include(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:43:40.071260 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:46818] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/local:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/community:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
[Fri Jan 24 18:43:40.071273 2014] [:error] [pid 2494] [client 127.0.0.1:46818] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247
*** glibc detected *** /opt/lampp/bin/httpd: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x08332630 ***
[Fri Jan 24 18:45:26.599938 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1502] AH00051: child pid 4245 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /opt/lampp
[Fri Jan 24 18:45:26.600073 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1502] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jan 24 18:45:33.065084 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 4991] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 24 18:45:33.065195 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 4991] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 24 18:45:33.065229 2014] [suexec:notice] [pid 4991] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /opt/lampp/bin/suexec)
[Fri Jan 24 18:45:33.199857 2014] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 4992] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jan 24 18:45:34.051094 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 4992] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 24 18:45:34.051151 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 4992] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 24 18:45:34.051205 2014] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 4992] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Jan 24 18:45:34.058057 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4992] AH00163: Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 24 18:45:34.058118 2014] [core:notice] [pid 4992] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -D SSL -D PHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log'
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, there is a mysql error, server has gone away... you should first check, if the webserver can access the db server.

second thing is when you perform an update, especially a majorversion upgrade, make sure that you switch your themes and packages back to the default magento ones, as layoutchanges can cause strange error messages or blank pages. hopefully this was not done on a productive website ;)

Then I would clear the whole cache. If you do not have access to backend, simply remove any files and folders below /docroot/var/cache/ and reload the page after clearing browsercache as well.

If that did not help see if there any frontend errors displayed. If not and only a blank page is displayed or just parts of page with the rest of it blank, it is very hekpful to enable error reporting on frontend in php and magento.

Then you should always take a look on your magentolog found in /docroot/var/log... especially exception.log and system.log can contain a bunch of helpful things...

If you need more help, send over some more info.

Cheers
Ben

Comment: everytime i am upgrading the magento the Mysql server is gone away at last stage when i execute the command ./mage upgrade-all –-force 
after that i am required to reinstall the xampp everytime 
could you help on this

Comment: what do you meant by default theme shall i switch to default theme ie default design from backend drop down of design .?
pls ellaborate 
thanks

Comment: Warning: include(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/local:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/community:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247